# Bootbox and bootstrap elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I wanted to display a bootbox. But I wondered what elements from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) are used. 
Because I do not want to screw up all my current CSS. 
I would just take the necessary CSS code.

Comment: Show us some code , that you are working with  , or trying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootbox uses Twitter Bootstrap Modals. Custom modals, other than the alert/confirm bootboxes, are filled with a custom Bootbox input field. This is not an Input  from Bootstrap. Also every modal uses Bootstrap Buttons.